# tensorflow stop_gradient equivalent in pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

What is the `tf.stop_gradient()` equivalent (provides a way to not compute gradient with respect to some variables during back-propagation) in pytorch?

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/what-is-the-use-of-torch-no-grad-in-pytorch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816241/difference-between-detach-and-with-torch-nograd-in-pytorch/56817594

Answer (score 24):

Could you check with x.detach().

Comment: Link to the documentation : https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html

Answer (score 7):

Tensors in pytorch have [`requires_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.requires_grad_) attribute. Set it to `False` to prevent gradient computation for that tensors.