# Difference between "detach()" and "with torch.nograd()" in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I know about two ways to exclude elements of a computation from the gradient calculation `backward`

**Method 1:** using `with torch.no_grad()`

```
with torch.no_grad():
    y = reward + gamma * torch.max(net.forward(x))
loss = criterion(net.forward(torch.from_numpy(o)), y)
loss.backward();
```

**Method 2:** using `.detach()`

```
y = reward + gamma * torch.max(net.forward(x))
loss = criterion(net.forward(torch.from_numpy(o)), y.detach())
loss.backward();
```

Is there a difference between these two? Are there benefits/downsides to either?

Answer (score 106):

`tensor.detach()` creates a tensor that shares storage with tensor that does not require grad. It detaches the output from the computational graph. So no gradient will be backpropagated along this variable.

The wrapper `with torch.no_grad()` temporarily set all the `requires_grad` flag to false. `torch.no_grad` says that no operation should build the graph.

The difference is that one refers to only a given variable on which it is called. The other affects all operations taking place within the `with` statement. Also, `torch.no_grad` will use less memory because it knows from the beginning that no gradients are needed so it doesn’t need to keep intermediary results.

Learn more about the differences between these along with examples from [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/detach-no-grad-and-requires-grad/16915/10).

Comment: Just a small note, `with torch.no_grad()` doesn't turn off the `requires_grad` flag in all tensors. Only the new tensors created inside the context manager have `requires_grad` `False`, other tensors stay the same.
 ```import torch

y = torch.tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True)
print(y)

with torch.no_grad():
 new_tensor = y * 2
 print(new_tensor.requires_grad)
 print(y.requires_grad)
```
Output:
```tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
False
True```

Answer (score 59):

#### `detach()`

One example without `detach()`:

```
from torchviz import make_dot
x=torch.ones(2, requires_grad=True)
y=2*x
z=3+x
r=(y+z).sum()    
make_dot(r)
```

[image]

The end result in green `r` is a root of the AD computational graph and in blue is the leaf tensor.

Another example with `detach()`:

```
from torchviz import make_dot
x=torch.ones(2, requires_grad=True)
y=2*x
z=3+x.detach()
r=(y+z).sum()    
make_dot(r)
```

[image]

This is the same as:

```
from torchviz import make_dot
x=torch.ones(2, requires_grad=True)
y=2*x
z=3+x.data
r=(y+z).sum()    
make_dot(r)
```

But, `x.data` is the old way (notation), and `x.detach()` is the new way.

What is the difference with `x.detach()`

```
print(x)
print(x.detach())
```

Out:

```
tensor([1., 1.], requires_grad=True)
tensor([1., 1.])
```

So `x.detach()` is a way to remove `requires_grad` and what you get is a new *detached* tensor (detached from AD computational graph).

#### torch.no_grad

[`torch.no_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html) is actually a class.

```
x=torch.ones(2, requires_grad=True)
with torch.no_grad():
    y = x * 2
print(y.requires_grad)
```

Out:

```
False
```

From `help(torch.no_grad)`:

> Disabling gradient calculation is useful for inference, when you are sure
> |  that you will not call :meth:`Tensor.backward()`. It will reduce memory
> |  consumption for computations that would otherwise have `requires_grad=True`.
> |
> |  In this mode, the result of every computation will have
> |  `requires_grad=False`, even when the inputs have `requires_grad=True`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers... gives a quick intuitive overview of the .data and detach functions in the computation graph

Comment: @prosti What is the full form & meaning of AD?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=AD+computational+graph&t=newext&atb=v251-1&ia=web second link on Wikipedia

Answer (score 8):

A simple and profound explanation is that use of `with torch.no_grad()` behaves just like a loop where everything written in it will have there `requires_grad` argument set as `False` although temporarily. So there is no need to specify anything beyond this if you need to stop the backpropagation from gradients of certain variables or functions.

However, `torch.detach()` simply detaches the variable from the gradient computation graph as the name suggests. But this is used when this specification has to be provided for a limited number of variables or functions for eg. generally while displaying the loss and accuracy outputs after an epoch ends in neural network training because at that moment, it only consumed resourced since its gradient won't matter in during the display of results.